# Report preview on screen too small

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-reports

I have a report that is generated as a print preview with a click from a menu form.  It comes up as very small on the screen and would have to be maximized or resized by the user each time.  Is there a way to pre-set the report height and width on the screen?  I would like it the height of the screen and whatever width it needs to be proportional (i.e.: 8.5 x 11).  If I open the report directly from access (not the menu form) it does not do this (although it is still small than I'd like).

[image: screen grab from my monitor]

Comment: Reports are intended for print and forms for screen. Making one behave as the other is seldom fully satisfactory. Print Preview is supposed to show what the print will look like, not be used to analyze data. Your report already seems to use up most of the available window height. Have you tried `DoCmd.Maximize`?

Comment: Yep,  there it goes.  Missed that one in my searching.  Thanks.